# SOLR query with multiple fields using Not Equals operator with OR returns wrong result

Tags: syntax, solr

I am trying to perform a solr query with multiple query fields including a not equals operator.

Example query:

```
field1:abc OR -field2:def
```

The problem is the query returns results for an **AND** operation instead of an **OR**, as if the query was:

```
field1:abc AND -field2.def
```

Both queries always return the same result. What is the correct syntax to achieve a correct OR result?

I am currently using solr 3.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try the following:

```
field1:abc OR (*:* -field2:def)
```

Answer (score 0):

for field1:abc OR -field2:def this also works

-(-field1:abc AND field2:def) .