# Solr list entries for A-B condition on same field

Tags: solr

I have multiple records

```
name1 employee building1
name2 employee building1
name3 manager  building1
name4 manager  building1
name5 employee building2
name4 manager  building2
```

I want to fetch all managers with `building1` access but not with `building2` access.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOLR query with multiple fields using Not Equals operator with OR returns wrong result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855122/solr-query-with-multiple-fields-using-not-equals-operator-with-or-returns-wrong)

Comment: can you explain how this applies to in building1 but not in building2 for same field building . I tried  (+building:building1 -building:building2) its not working. the example provided by you  is for 2 fields and not filtering on same field's values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> (field1:manager AND field2:building1) AND (NOT(field1:manager AND field2:building2))

Note:check for syntax.

It means fetch (manager who has access to building1) AND (manager don't have access to building2) 
or

> (field1:manager AND field2:building1 AND (NOT(field2:building2)))

manager with access to building1 and not to building2